# Like Button issues using iPad/Kiosk software integration

Tags: facebook-like, kiosk

I have created a web page based on the log-in (facebook) specs that works correctly through IE, Safari, Mozilla. I'm trying to set-up an ipad running a Kiosk software program. The link that I have works correctly, but when it comes to the sign-in on facebook it stalls via iPad/Kiosk software. I contacted the software support team with Kiosk, and this is what was said

"It looks like the problem is caused by Kiosk Pro's inability to open more than one window; this is a result of having to use Apple's UI Web View browser as the base browser of Kiosk Pro and is not something we can change. Opening your page in Safari or a desktop browser the Facebook page opens as a separate pop-up over top of your page, which remains open even after the Facebook page closes. In Kiosk Pro, since there is no way to open another window, the Facebook link is navigated to inside the main window and there is no way for the user to get back to your main page (short of hitting the home button or idle timing out) once they have finished the facebook process. Unfortunately, this is a structural issue that I don't have any easy solutions for."

Is there any work around, etc. that anyone can guide me to resolve this issue. What I'm trying to do, it use an ipad as a kiosk to allow people to "like" my store as they visit. However, I'm using the Kiosk software to prevent the user from accessing any further info, web browsing, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks